# About The Vote Down Thing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes

The "vote down" thing is making everyone avoid answering to the question, and when someone votes down they feel like god. It destroys the fun of asking questions here.

I am looking for answers not for vote downs!

The vote thing should be on the answer's of the question and not on the question it self...

This community is breaking down; Even the answers are bad. We should just remove it without more questions, or maybe just remove it from the questioner's question.

You can change it? Avoid from this "question" tags. Forget for a moment the laws of this community, and take what I wrote seriously!

Comment: Bad questions will be voted down.

Comment: The problem isn't the question, it is how people ask the question. Don't just say I have a problem, let people know specifically what the problem is and post relevant code. If you don't know what the relative code is, that is the problem, you have jumped into something over your head and shouldn't be asking the question you are asking anyway. This is about helping people progress as programmers and solve complex bugs that have created headaches... not solve peoples homework problems or use google for them.

Comment: vote downs will not help to the questioner -_- he here for answers believe me...

Comment: Learning how to ask a question will most certainly help a questioner, or better let learning to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Lol @the road of death.

Comment: It does not stop me answering at all - infact it does the opposite and makes sure any answer i construct is (hopefully) understandable, clear, and useful. I expect the same from questions and I down vote *a lot* of questions where it is obvious no effort has gone into their construction

Comment: I think thad questions and answers should down voted, **BUT** i believe that people should say why there upvote or downvote in order to help.

Comment: Asking a good question is more likely to get you good answers.

Comment: -1 for punctuation, grammar, lack of paragraphs, organization, cryptic  abbreviations and emoticons(?) etc. AND for ` the fun of asking questions here` - it should be about utility not "fun", its not a game you know

Comment: @kostasch. When someone comes along and says "I can't do this - can you give me teh codez" is it really necessary to explain that isn't how the site works each time?

Comment: It appears you're angry.   Don't be.  StackOverflow is a community with certain rules.  Just follow the rules here, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @user3685898 the questioner wants a good answer, and who responds want a good question :)

Comment: People looking for a quick answer, do not create a tool that lets someone ignore the request of the person, just try it for 1 Month and u will see how your community will prosper

Comment: Oh my gosh it's like reading a text message from your worst nightmare...

Comment: @Daniel Kelley i think yes, you have to explain to him in order to learn. and i think the purpose of this site is to help people to learn :)

Comment: When people make unreasonable requests like "give me the codez" we should have a tool that allows us to easily ignore those people. It's not a personal attack on them, that's just not what the site is for.

Comment: @user3685898 - The [one question you had down-voted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23933371/1324033) is very broad, doesn't show any research effort, and in general is a little bit clustered and hard to understand what you are hoping to gain from an answer.

Comment: @user3685898 I'd guess you are referring to [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933371/this-is-very-interesting-about-sockets). It was clearly explained that as is it's too broad, and cannot reasonable be answered without you giving more context. So what's your concern actually??

Comment: If you are bring a person the code you are saving him time, and in this world there is no time to waste, please help even to those that having difficulties

Comment: @user3685898 If you can't be bothered to read the guide on asking questions or do the bare amount of research why should we be bothered to answer you?

Comment: There is no time to waste, yet here you are wasting everyones time!

Comment: No, screw that. This site isn't for providing lazy, incompetent "coders" with code.

Comment: Answering and asking are all part of a big, common learning process for everyone involved. You learn by answering and you learn by good asking (even before you receive any answer). Bad answers as well as bad questions damage this (IMO) scientific atmosphere.

Comment: Look at how many of you attacked me, no one understands that if u will give the code to the questioner he will be Satisfied + Without the Headaches :/

Comment: By giving someone code and not teaching him how to write it/learn, you are saving his time now, but wasting your own time and the time of everyone else that answers his bad questions in the future. And when no one has time to give him the code, he won't be able to write it himself. So he'll waste more time. See how that works?

Comment: @user3685898 Absolutely no one has 'attacked' you at all.

Comment: I don't want to "satisfy" you, I want you and me to learn something in the process.

Comment: @user3685898 "in this world there is no time to waste" - indeed and there is little time to waste on poorly asked, rambling, incoherent questions or ones where the poster has expended zero effort and research and just wants someone else to code/debug/both his previous amateur efforts.

Comment: If it was just about satisfying the asker, he should pay for someone to write code for him, not expect a bunch of volunteers to do it to prevent his headaches out of the kindness of their hearts.

Comment: @user3685898 - and what about our headaches? do you have any idea how many hundreds of poor questions get asked daily? its hard to help those that have truly thought about those questions when you spend your time on ill-formatted questions, We're not attacking you, we're defending the sites format

Comment: @Savanna it's not true, when someone getting a code he will remember this code and will try to understand it and it make him even Smarter!!!

Comment: No, when someone gets an *explanation* of how code works after *trying it himself first* and running into specific issues, he will learn. It's not about learning how to solve one specific problem, it's about learning how to solve problems yourself...

Comment: give a man a fish and he eats for a day; teach him to fish...

Comment: @Plutonix and he'll overfish the ocean and destroy the ecosystem? :)

Comment: I remember that before 1 year someone gave me a code, no one have any idea how much it helped me and because of this code i keep building applications , i have learned from his code how to write my code in A better way, It made my heart good feeling, I was happy that day and that application that i have built help many other humans

Comment: That's great, good for you. But the thing is, so many questions have been asked here before, there's already so much code available if people will just *look* for it. And a lot of people don't even put in that much effort. Hence, downvoting.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from this discussion/rant? Accept that your question was voted for the reasons it was, and either improve it in an attempt to get an answer or forget it and move on - then when you need to ask another question, make sure it is clear and well thought out.

Comment: just someone please think seriously about removing this tool, it will make the asker smarter + will make u smarter + Save time + Give a person what he really looking for + Will make this community grow :)

Comment: @user3685898 You've made your case, but I can guarantee you this will never happen.

Comment: ok , delete this discussion... :/

Comment: No, I agree.  People get voted down even when they are new and don't know how the stackoverflow system works yet.  I mean, I thought the point of stackoverflow was to solve problems and help people become better at what they do.  Not criticize them for forgetting to post something in their code.  People are more worried about being elitist these days rather than actually helping other people become better.

And yeah, many topics already exists.  But by trial and error we know that not every solution will work for every person with the same issue/problem.

Comment: Vote down on questions is to discourage writing obvious questions and those without thought. If others are willing to spend their precious time on answering it, we don't want to make them feel like their time is wasted reading and answering something that's already been answered or doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -11):

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Because I certainly don't feel like a god when I downvote.

Comment: You mean you don't downvote out of a mean-spirited pleasure you get from hurting people's feelings and causing them to get no answers? ;P

Comment: @Savanna I never said that ;)

Comment: Step 1. Vote Step 2. Tilt head back Step 3. Raise arms to the heavens Step 4. Laugh maniacally with enough force to create thunder and lightning.

Comment: You're not downvoting enough, that's your problem.  Your upvote/downvote ratio is just way, way too high.  it appears that you're not downvoting all of the bad posts that you actually read.

Comment: @Servy what website we talking about here?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Well originally I looked at SO, and felt that while your ratio is certainly much better than the average, it's still below my experiences in using the site (and you're active in tags with noticeably worse post quality, such as PHP).  Having looked through some of the sites you use other than SO, you almost never downvote on any of them.  That seems odd to me (although I'm not active on most, so I couldn't speak to average post quality).  That said, to be fair, I feel that almost everyone on the site doesn't downvote enough, so I would have posted that comment to almost anyone.

Comment: @Servy Since the MSE/MSO split, my vote count here is almost nothing. On MSE on the other hand, it appears I almost _never_ downvote (4180 up; 221 down). But that's just because it's meta.

Comment: @downvoter Do you feel like a god?

Comment: … unclear what you're answering.